# How to render the component with onClick in another jsx file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to hide or block the music player component when onClick of a button.

[image]

When the Music button in the navbar is pressed the music player at the bottom should hide or block. The problem is the components are in different files.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { BiSkipPrevious, BiSkipNext, BiPause, BiPlay } from 'react-icons/bi';
import { songs } from '../assets/items';

Here is the code for Musicplayer,

export default function MusicPlayer() {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true)
  const [isPlayAnime, setIsPlayAnime] = useState(false)
  const totalSongs = songs.length
  let songIdx = 0
  const [song, setSong] = useState({info: songs[songIdx], audioSrc: new Audio(songs[songIdx].audio)})

  const [view, setView] = useState(true)

  const prevSong = () => {
    if(songIdx < 0) {
      songIdx = 0
    } else {
      songIdx = songIdx - 1
    }
    setSong({info: songs[songIdx], audioSrc: new Audio(songs[songIdx].audio)})
  }

  const nextSong = () => {
    if(songIdx > totalSongs - 1) {
      songIdx = 0
    } else {
      songIdx = songIdx + 1
    }
    setSong({info: songs[songIdx], audioSrc: new Audio(songs[songIdx].audio)})
  }

  const playSong = () => {
    setIsPlaying(false)
    setIsPlayAnime(!isPlayAnime);
    song.audioSrc.play()
  }

  const pauseSong = () => {
    setIsPlaying(true)
    setIsPlayAnime(!isPlayAnime);
    song.audioSrc.pause()
  }

  return (
      <div>
        {view && (<div className={`music-container ${isPlayAnime ? `play` : ""}`}>
          <div className='music-wrapper'>
            <div className='music-info'>
                <h4 id='title'>{song.info.title}</h4>
            </div>
            <div className='img-container'>
                <img src={song.info.image} alt='music-cover' id='cover'/>
            </div>
            <div className='navigation'>
              <button id="prev" className='btn-prev action-btn' onClick={prevSong}>
                <BiSkipPrevious fontSize='3rem' />
              </button>
              {isPlaying === true ? (<button id="play" className='btn-play action-btn-big' onClick={playSong}>
                <BiPlay fontSize='4rem' />
              </button>) :  <button id="pause" className='btn-play action-btn-big' onClick={pauseSong}>
                <BiPause fontSize='4rem' />
              </button>
              }
              <button id="next" className='btn-next action-btn' onClick={nextSong} >
                <BiSkipNext fontSize='3rem' />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>)}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the code for navbar,

```
import React from 'react'
import SunIcon from './Icons/SunIcon'
import MoonIcon from './Icons/MoonIcon'
import avatar from '../assets/avatar.jpeg'
import '../css/skeleton.css'
import '../css/normalize.css'
import '../css/components.css'
import { ThemeType } from '../ts/types';
import { BiMusic } from 'react-icons/bi'

function Header(): JSX.Element {
  const dataTheme = document.body.getAttribute('data-theme');
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState<ThemeType>((): ThemeType => dataTheme === "light" ? "light" : 'dark');
  const [viewMusic, setViewMusic] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', theme)
  }, [theme]);

  const handleSwitchTheme = () => {
    setTheme(isDark ? 'light' : 'dark')
  }

  const isDark = theme === 'dark'

  const handleMusicComponent = () => {
    setViewMusic(!viewMusic)
  }

  return (
      <div className="Header container">
        <div className="ten columns Header__inner">
          <img src={avatar} alt="avatar" />
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <h2>
            <b>Sagnik. </b>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <button className='music-btn' onClick={handleMusicComponent}>
          <BiMusic fontSize="2.5rem"/>
        </button>
        <button className="switch-theme-button" onClick={handleSwitchTheme}>
          {isDark ? <SunIcon color="white" /> : <MoonIcon  />}
        </button>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Help needed!

Comment: [useContext](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useContext)?

Comment: You should use useContext hook.

Answer (score 0):

So the naive way to do this would be to find the common ancestor of these two components and add a state variable there and then drill that variable as props down to the two components and make your changes based on the prop.

```js
function P() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState();
  return <> <A foo={foo}/> <B foo={foo}/> </>;
}

function A(props) {
  // return something here based on props.foo
}

function B(props) {
  // return something here based on props.foo
}
```

The smarter way to do this would be to use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for react ([useContext hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)). It acts as a data store and subscribes to the changes for the data in the store.

Here is the example from the React docs for useContext.

```js
const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: "#000000",
    background: "#eeeeee"
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: "#ffffff",
    background: "#222222"
  }
};

const ThemeContext = React.createContext(themes.light);

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={themes.dark}>
      <Toolbar />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemedButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function ThemedButton() {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <button style={{ background: theme.background, color: theme.foreground }}>
      I am styled by theme context!
    </button>
  );
}
```